# Increment integers from another class

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this code in my Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public static int hours;
    public static int minutes;
    public static int seconds;
    FinishGate finishgate = new FinishGate();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        txtHours.MaxLength = 2;
        txtMinutes.MaxLength = 2;
        txtSeconds.MaxLength = 2;

        lblFinished.Text = Convert.ToString(gate.Total);
    }

private void btnFinish_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        hours = Convert.ToInt32(txtHours.Text);
        minutes = Convert.ToInt32(txtMinutes.Text);
        seconds = Convert.ToInt32(txtSeconds.Text);
        lblFinished.Text = Convert.ToString(gate.Total);

        // Check if a runner has been selected
        if (lstRunners.SelectedIndex > -1)
        {
            // Obtain selected runner
            Runner selectedRunner = (Runner)lstRunners.SelectedItem;

            // If runner hasn't finished
            if (selectedRunner.HasFinished == false)
            {
                // Call the method in FinishGate class to process the runner
                FinishGate.ProcessRunner(selectedRunner);
            }
            else
            {
                // Runner has finished / been processed so increase the total that have completed the climb by one
                finishgate.Total++;
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Here is the FinishGate.cs:

```
class Gate
{
    private int total;

    public int Total
    {
        get { return total; }
        set { total = value; }
    }

    public static void ProcessRunner(Runner selectedRunner)
    {

    }
}
```

What I want to happen is that when a runner in the listbox is selected and the Process button is clicked, the boolean `hasFinished` in `ProcessRunner` is changed to `true` and the `Total` integer is increased by one, which then updates the `lblFinished` to also increase by one, but I can't get it to work.

My two main issues are: I'm not sure what the code would be in `ProcessRunner()` to say if `hasFinished == false` change it to true, `else` leave the boolean the way it is. The other issue is getting the `lblFinished` to update accordingly when the integer increments.

Any advice over where I'm going wrong and how to prevent this in the future would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

Put this line

`lblFinished.Text = Convert.ToString(gate.Total);`

at the end of the `btnFinish_Click()` event instead of the beginning. This way it will update **after** `ProcessRunner()` is run.

Also, add this to your `ProcessRunner()` event in your `Gate` class:

```
if (selectedRunner.hasFinished == false)
{
    selectedRunner.hasFinished = true;
}
//You don't need to do anything if it isn't false.
```

I hope this is of use to you. Let me know if I need to be more specific.